# Sum of ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, foreach

Is there any way to find the sum of all the elements of the lists within the `inputList`?

This is what I've tried but this only works with a regular ArrayList Integer I assume.

```
static int add(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> inputList) {
    int a = (int) inputList;
    int sum = 0;

    for(int d : a)
        sum = sum + d;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `int a = (int) inputList;` what are expecting from it?

Comment: do you mean to add all the elements of the lists within the outer ArrayList?, because currently, your code won't compile.

Comment: The contents of the input ArrayList

Comment: No the sum of the contents, the input should be a list of integers

Comment: The input _isn't_ a list of integers. It's a list of lists of integers.

Comment: Hint: create a method to sum a `List<Integer>`, apply twice.

Comment: @9000 surely the first time we use this method we pass some `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` to it and get an error?

Comment: Is there a way? Yes. --- Why do you *assume* that your code works with a regular ArrayList Integer? Didn't you *try*? Well, obviously not, because that code won't even compile, regardless of parameter type.

Comment: @patrick-hainge: First time you pass _every element_ of the `List<List<Integer>>` to the summing method, and create a `List<Integer>` of partial sums; then sum them. Or, of course, you can just write two nested loops.

Comment: `return inputList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).mapToInt(i -> i).sum();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't cast an ArrayList to an integer primitive type, so you should remove that line. For the same reason, you can't use your enhanced for-loop, because the parameter is an ArrayList of ArrayLists of Integers.

```
static int add(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> inputList) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(ArrayList<Integer> nestedList : inputList) {
        for (int n : nestedList) sum += n;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to go about it is by using a nested `foreach` loop to iterate over the outer list and inner lists then simply add all the elements together.

```
static int add(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> inputList) {
       int sum = 0;
       for (ArrayList<Integer> list : inputList) {
           for (int number : list) {
                sum += number;
           }
       } 
       return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java8 streams to find the sum as shown in the below code with a single line (follow the comments):

```
int sum = inputList.stream().//get the stream for the outer list
           flatMapToInt(list -> list.stream().
            mapToInt(value -> value)).//flatten the inner list
            sum();//get the sum
```

Comment: You're wrapping every Integer in a new stream, and then immediately flattening it. Why?!

Comment: It's still a bit convoluted (see my [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788868/sum-of-arraylistarraylistinteger/43789007?noredirect=1#comment74619850_43788868)), and the formatting is... unusual.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple solutions:

```
import java.util.List;

class Class {
  public int addViaLoops(List<List<Integer>> inputList) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (final List<Integer> l : inputList) {
      for (final int i : l) {
        sum += i;
      }
    }
    return sum;
  }

  public int addViaStreams(List<List<Integer>> inputList) {
    return inputList.stream()
      .flatMapToInt(l -> l.stream()
        .mapToInt(i -> i))
      .sum();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
static int add(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> inputList){

    int sum = 0; // initiate sum to zero.

    for (ArrayList<Integer> list: inputList) {

        for (Integer i: list) {

            sum += i.intValue(); // intValue() might not be necessary, but it doesn't hurt
        }
    }

    return sum;
 }
```

The above code should be pretty straightforward. Using a foreach loop, we can iterate all of the lists in `inputList`, and then we can iterate through each list and add its value to `sum`.

Where you do...

```
int a = (int) inputList;int a = (int) inputList;

int sum = 0;
for(int d : a)
    sum = sum + d;
```

...isn't going to work because you're trying to convert an List of Lists of Integers into an int.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
 inputList.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
```